# Generated php results appear and then promptly disappear

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am trying to create a tutorial bookmarker project. The idea is that the bookmarked tutorials are supposed to load when the page opens. I am trying to display the results from the mysql database using php, for some reason the results only display for half a second and then disappear.

I have spent ages trying to figure out how to fix it and have had no luck. I think it might have something to do with the while loop but not sure.

I have created a class that contains the simple load bookmarks function.

```
<?php 
class Bookmarked {

private $con;

public function __construct($con) {
    $this->con = $con;
}

public function loadBookmarks(){

    $str = "";
    $data = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM bookmarked ORDER BY id DESC");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($data);

    if($count == 0){
        echo "No bookmarks saved";
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

        echo "In while loop";

        $tutname = $row['tutname'];
        $tutdescription = $row['tutdescription'];
        $tuturl = $row['tuturl'];
        $date_added = $row['date_added'];

        $str .= "<div class='well'>
                    <h3>$tutname</h3> <hr> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
                    <p>$tutdescription</p> <br>
                    <a class='btn btn-primary' href='#'><i class='fas fa-check'></i></a>
                    <a class='btn btn-default' href='$tuturl' target='_blank'><i class='fas fa-search'></i></a>
                    <a class='btn btn-danger' href='#' onclick='deleteBookmark()'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>
                </div>";
       }
       echo "Out of while loop";
       echo $str;
    }
  }
?>
```

I am trying to call it as shown below

```
<?php

 include("includes/header.php");
 include("includes/classes/Bookmarked.php");

?>

  <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Tutorials Bookmarked</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="bookmarksResults">
        <?php 
          $bookmark = new Bookmarked($con);
          $bookmark->loadBookmarks(); //Calling the loadBookmarks() function
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried search for an answer but couldn't find anything. If this isn't clear enough I will explain further.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have some code somewhere in the page which causes a refresh, or a redirect, or some other change to the page after you've loaded it. It's not in the code you've shown, but it's probably somewhere else in the whole code which makes up that page and is delivered to the browser.

Comment: after further investigating I found it. I just needed to know whether it was in this or not. thanks for the help. Is there a better way to do what I have shown above?